# Преобразование числа (лет, месяцев, дней) java

Tags: java, преобразование

Собственно проблема в том что получаю сумму дней из определённых периодов времени. К примеру 367 - > как и этого числа получить вывод-  1 год, 0 месяцев, 2 дня. Год вывести просто а вот с остальным не могу придумать... Что бы выводило не более 12 и 30 дней/месяцев.
Подскажите у кого какие мысли пожалуйста.

```
if (box.isSelected()) {
                LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.parse(first_date_compression_start.getText(), formatter);
                LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.parse(first_date_compression_end.getText(), formatter);
                DAYS = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate);
                result_sum.setText(DAYS + " д.");
            }
if (box1.isSelected()) {
                LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.parse(first_date_compression_start1.getText(), formatter);
                LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.parse(first_date_compression_end1.getText(), formatter);
                DAYS += ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate);
                result_sum.setText(DAYS + " д.");
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование числа (лет, месяцев, дней)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1228294/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

Все просто:

```
Period period = Period.between(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(367));
System.out.println("" +
        "Years: " + period.getYears() + "; " +
        "Months: " + period.getMonths() + "; " +
        "Days: " + period.getDays() + ";");
```

Результат:

```
> Task :Main.main()
Years: 1; Months: 0; Days: 2;
```

Comment: Не так-то и просто. Результат будет зависеть от сегодяшней даты. Сравните результаты для начальной даты 1 января и 31 декабря високосного года.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну ладно, согласен, эту часть отдам на фантазию вопрошающего.

Comment: @Эникейщик не то) я делаю JFX которая считает стаж работы, по этому приведение к сегодняшнему дню не подходит. Т.е. у меня 18 окон, с - по -, где я пытаюсь сделать вывод итого из заполненных окон, получилось довольно несуразно (хотя и работает) но пока могу вывести только в днях (https://github.com/VaSeBa/AssistantForHR).

Comment: @DmitryD не то) я делаю JFX которая считает стаж работы, по этому приведение к сегодняшнему дню не подходит. Т.е. у меня 18 окон, с - по -, где я пытаюсь сделать вывод итого из заполненных окон, получилось довольно несуразно (хотя и работает) но пока могу вывести только в днях (https://github.com/VaSeBa/AssistantForHR).